# VM Support for Custom PCIe Interface

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, pci-express

We have a MS Windows application that talks to external equipment over a custom PCIe interface and a performance sensitive environment. We would like to enable the application to run on a VM. This would allow users to quickly switch between OS configurations on the same physical hardware. 
What does it take to do something like this? Are there consulting services that provide these kind of solutions?
TIA

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is a feature of VMware "vSphere ESX Vcenter":

> VMDirectPath I/O allows a guest operating system on a virtual machine to directly access physical PCI and PCIe devices connected to a host. Each virtual machine can be connected to up to six PCI devices.

https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-4-esx-vcenter/index.jsp?topic=/com.vmware.vsphere.vmadmin.doc_41/vc_client_help/managing_virtual_machine_hardware_and_devices/t_add_passthrough_device.html